# How to perform action on the basis of response status while doing sync in Ext.js

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

This is my store MyStore.js

```
Ext.define('myProject.store.MyStore', {
    config:{
        storeId:    'MyStore',
        autoLoad:   false,
        autoSync:   false,
        allowSingle: true,
        clearOnPageLoad:    true,

        model:              'abc.model.MyStoreModel',
        proxy: {
            type:   'rest',
            actionMethods: {create: 'POST', read: 'GET', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'},
              url:'/services/rest/MyService/myService',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty:MyServiceView.elements.collection',
                successProperty : 'success'
            },
            writer:
            {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'MyServiceDataView',
                nameProperty: 'mapping',
                expandData : true
            },
            listeners: {
                exception:          function(proxy,response,operation){

                }
            }   
        }
    }
});
```

This is my Model

```
Ext.define( 'myProject.model.MyStoreModel', {
    extend:         'Ext.data.Model',
    config:{
        idProperty:     'keyStr',
        fields:[
                {
                    name:           'keyStr',
                    type:           'string',
                },
                {
                    name:           'sId',
                    type:           'int'
                },
                {
                    name:           'dCode',
                    type:           'string'
                },
                {
                    name:           'sNumber',
                    type:           'int'
                }

            ]
    },

});
```

Inside my Controller.js, I have this method

```
syncMyStore: function()
    {

        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var successfulSync= 'false';
        var me = this;
        var myStore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');

        if(this.isSyncRequires(myStore)) //assume this is always true
        {
            myStore.sync({
                success: function () {
                    successfulSync = 'true';
                    deferred.fulfill();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            deferred.fulfill();
        }
        return successfulSync;
    },
```

1. Suppose I have 5 records in my store i.e record0, record2 ... record4.
2. For each records, it is calling the Rest Service. So total 5 Rest calls

Requirement 1: Instead of using success property, I want to perform some actions on the basis of status code. 
i.e if status code is 200, then consider it success.

Requirement 2: After each rest call, I want to remove record/mark dirty as false on the basis of response status (200) for that particular record.

Means, suppose for record1 and record2 if status code is 200, then I want to remove/mark dirty=false for record 1 and record2 only.

I will be really thankful for you if you help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that record0, record1, record3 .. have some unique way of identification. Make an ajax call for each record(REST api call ) then if the response is 200, control will hit "success" function. Then if the response has data to identify records select that record and change its dirty flag to false. In the failure function do the same and change dirty flag to true. 
There are two things you need to conform to make better answer

> 1. Will you be using records as payload for your rest api call ?
> 2. Will the response have indication record, i.e i'll have guid related to
>      record ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using records as payload for rest api call.
No, response do not have indication record. 
Problem is, control is not hitting success function. As you can see, successfulSync = 'true'; is inside the success and even after status is 200, it is not making it true.

Comment: Please do add failure also and add debugger in bot success and failure. Either of those two functions should be called.If success is not executed in your case then I guess it's executing failure. It'll help you further investigate the problem.

Comment: I have added success, failure and callback. After sync, it is not going into any of this.

Comment: Could you observe the network tab of chrome and check if POST http call is actually happening ?

Comment: Post call is actually happening but it is remain in 'pending' state while doing debugging

Comment: So if debugger is removed, POST call returns with status 200 ?

Comment: Then it should reach success function. There is something missing beyond this part of code. You can try creating a fresh application and add only this part of code to test. You can create a fiddle like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/prajavk/bf9ts/) and share

Comment: Hi Just one more thing. Does successful sync automatically set dirty : false ?

Comment: Node, you need to do it explicitly.

Comment: I'm new to the Extjs. Can you please help me where to do the modifications. Or how to do it. Please.